# Best way for a user to specify budget/price range?

Tags: gui-design, web-app, e-commerce, shopping-cart

When designing for a shopping service, the user should be able to specify what they're willing to spend on an item.

Problems:

- There's no automated way to know what price range on the item, so the entry is essentially free form.
- Users are bad at estimating prices: numerical input doesn't work
- Using a slider to classify user priority (e.g. economy, value, performance) leaves too much to interpretation
- Price ranges may not be granular enough for some users

How would you solve this UX issue?

Comment: A bit confused here: you have an ecomnerce site where the price people pay is decided by them and not you? The only situation I can think of for this is an auction site, in which case you set a minimum starting price. However, your situation doesn't read like one where multiple people bid, just that the buyer picks the price. Is this correct?

Comment: @JonW maybe he meant it in a search context

Comment: @fdmsaraiva: In search context, his assumptions are false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By shopping service, I am assuming that you mean a service where the user will enter a product, certain specifications and a price, and then your team will go out and source the product for them.

I think in your case, entering a maximum price they are willing to pay would be the best. Everyone would like to get the cheapest price for a given item (provided we are comparing the exact same item/service), so there isn't much sense in having a minimum price. However, you can improve this by searching [Google Shopping](http://www.google.com/shopping) and [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/) and perhaps even a few major online stores/retailers in the region you are targetting this service.

This should allow you to provide the user with a general idea of how much the item typically costs, allowing them to entering an appropriate range for the price.

A possible interface could look like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f10uSX.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Given this, you have hinted to the user how much the item typically costs, and allowed them to enter a reasonable value for your service to work with. You can also build an algorithm to reject unreasonable maximum prices. For example, if the user asks you to source him a Ferrari which typically sells for $500,000, but provides a maximum price of $1, your system can automatically reject that immediately.

If you are not comfortable providing a list of products from third parties like amazon, you can aggregate the prices and process them using an algorithm to result in something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgdOjS.png)</sup>

Comment: Great answer, thanks! We arrived at a similar answer internally and should be putting it into effect in the coming months.